# Facebook connection/communication with AS3 only?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

the title pretty much sums it up. Is it possible to establish a connection with facebook using flash AS3 "only", without having to work with Javascript, html, iframes or any other externals.

The reason is a simple game I was making for android using AdobeAir that connects with facebook for leaderboard purposes. Works quite well, ofcourse with AdobeAir you get the flash internal webview and ANEs to help with the facebook communication. But outside AdobeAir, as a simple web-aimed swf file you dont.

Since I was hoping to make a web-version of the game and upload it to game-hosters, I was wondering if there is a way to make a connection and wrap it up in a single swf file, since thats what these sites want for upload.

Hopes are slim, yet I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of web interface to load the authorisation dialogue from Facebook. This is a popup with content running within Facebook itself, if the user then authorises your app Facebook will send a callback where you can get the access_token.

This is explained rather rudimental, the point being is that the authorisation is on Facebook ends, this is the security. In AIR you use StageWebView, in a browser you load the authorisation URL in a popup, this is implemented in the Javascript SDK for you.

You can put a button in Flash, use ExternalInterface to call methods in the Javascript SDK and send the access_token back as a callback. If you have the access_token you can use AS3 to make API calls with it in the form of HTTP requests.

Comment: ok thanks for your response, thats what I was thinking ... so it cannot be done in flash alone since it needs to show the login page somewhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a Facebook App? If your SWF is running inside the Facebook Canvas, of course it is more convenient to get the login information directly through official Javascript SDK, but if you want, this may help you. https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Comment: it is a facebook app and already has gamecenter approval, so yes. I did try the graph API you've mentioned, yet it always referred to the facebook-login using webview inside the as3 project ... but webview didnt seem to work outside AdobeAir.

Answer (score 0):

Any request you can write in JS, you can code in AS3 also. I don't see any problems, since FaceBook has 100% documented API.

Comment: requests maybe but how about the login procedure? I did get the graphAPI to work in the past, yet for the login it always wanted to use the flash webview feature which seems to be AdobeAir exclusive. Do you have tried or succeeded in having a completely AS3 (no Air) based facebook connection?

Comment: What the problem is with login request? FB returns nothing?